# Is it possible to take a project from VS 2010 to VS 2019

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dataset

So i am using a project from 2010 which is an online shoe shop and i am turning it into a medical equipment shop .

the problem is that it uses "crystalReports", which is something that I don't have

the problem comes with the back-end things , most of it doesn't work , I fixed most of it but I am stuck at wall which is the "Dataset" the webConfig and connection string are too outdated for me to use.

Code examples:

```
    {
       // The USER DATASET:
         
        DS_USER.USER_SELECTDataTable UDT = new DS_USER.USER_SELECTDataTable();
        DS_USERTableAdapters.USER_SELECTTableAdapter UAdapter = new DS_USERTableAdapters.USER_SELECTTableAdapter();

        DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable CDT = new DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable();
        DS_CATTableAdapters.CATEMST_SELECTTableAdapter CAdapter = new DS_CATTableAdapters.CATEMST_SELECTTableAdapter();

        DS_AITEM.ITEM_SELECTDataTable IDT = new DS_AITEM.ITEM_SELECTDataTable();
        DS_AITEMTableAdapters.ITEM_SELECTTableAdapter IAdapter = new DS_AITEMTableAdapters.ITEM_SELECTTableAdapter();
        



        // The PRODUCT DataSET:
    DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable CDT = new DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable();
    DS_CATTableAdapters.CATEMST_SELECTTableAdapter CAdapter = new DS_CATTableAdapters.CATEMST_SELECTTableAdapter();

    DS_AITEM.ITEM_SELECTDataTable IDT = new DS_AITEM.ITEM_SELECTDataTable();
    DS_AITEMTableAdapters.ITEM_SELECTTableAdapter IAdapter = new DS_AITEMTableAdapters.ITEM_SELECTTableAdapter();
    
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        IDT = IAdapter.SeleectTOP7();
        DataList1.DataSource = IDT;
        DataList1.DataBind();
        
            
            CDT = CAdapter.select();
            GridView1.DataSource = CDT;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            


        }

        public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["name"] = "search";
            Response.Redirect("Search.aspx?name=" + txtsearch.Text);
        }
        public void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Session["name"] = "cate";
            Response.Redirect("Search.aspx?name=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        }
        public void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            UDT = UAdapter.Seleect_FOR_LOGIN(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
            if (UDT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Session["uname"] = TextBox1.Text;
                Session["fname"] = UDT.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                Session["lname"] = UDT.Rows[0]["surname"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("User/Default.aspx");

            }
            else
            {

                lblerror.Text = "Error !!!";
            }
            
        }
```

So most of the adapters don't work because of the DATASET that i can't use

Here is an example of the original DATASET:

[image: The original DATASET]

Here is what I got:

[image: here is my DATASET]

At the end if there is a way to do this please tell me , even if the way is inconveniente.

Comment: Are you going from .Net Framework to .Net Core or from one version of .Net Framework to another version of it?

Comment: @SalikRafiq  I am going .Net Framework to a newer version of it

Comment: You need to use the designer on the adapter to reset the queries you had before. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?view=vs-2019